# XPath assertion in an xsd schema

Tags: xsd, assertion, xpath-2.0

I have the following xsd schema

```
 <?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
targetNamespace = "http://www.ludd21.com/kPartModel"
xmlns = "http://www.ludd21.com/kPartModel"
elementFormDefault="qualified"
>   
    <xs:element name="kPartModel">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element ref="kPartsPiece"  minOccurs="1" maxOccurs = "unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="modelName" type="xs:NCName" use = "required"/>
      </xs:complexType>
       <!--piecename must be unique within kpModel-->
      <xs:unique name= "kPartModel">
            <xs:selector xpath="*"/>
            <xs:field xpath= "@pieceName"/>
          </xs:unique>
    </xs:element>
    
    <xs:element name="kPartsPiece">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref= "kPartsList"/>
          </xs:sequence>         
          <xs:attribute name="pieceName" type="xs:NCName"/>
         <!-- if they exist previousnum and nextsnum must contain valid partNumber that is referring to a part in kpartsList-->
         <xs:assert test = "every $x in kPartsList/@previousnums satisfies exists(kPartsList/@partNumber)"/>
         <xs:assert test = "every $x in kPartsList/@nextsnums satisfies exists (kPartsList/@partNumber)"/>
        </xs:complexType>
        <!-- @partNumber is unique across kPartsList -->
        <xs:unique name= "kPartsList">
          <xs:selector xpath="*"/>
          <xs:field xpath= "@partNumber"/>
        </xs:unique>
    </xs:element>
  
    <xs:element name = "kPartsList" >
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:choice >
            <xs:element ref = "castOnPartSeg"/>
            <xs:element ref = "castOnPartPoint"/>
          </xs:choice>
          <xs:choice  minOccurs= "0" maxOccurs = "unbounded">
            <xs:element ref = "castOnPartSeg" />
            <xs:element ref = "castOnPartPoint" />
            <xs:element ref = "castOffPartSeg" />
            <xs:element ref = "castOffPartPoint"/>
            <xs:element ref = "joinPart"/>
            <xs:element ref = "splitPart" />
            <xs:element ref = "segSplitPart"/>  
          </xs:choice>
        </xs:sequence>        
      </xs:complexType>      
      </xs:element>
    
    
    <xs:element name="castOnPartPoint">
      <xs:complexType>
         <xs:attribute name ="nextsnum" type = "kpRefsList" use = "required"/>
         <xs:attribute name = "partNumber" type = "xs:nonNegativeInteger" use = "required"/>
         <xs:attribute name = "heightd" type = "decimal5digits" use = "required"/>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
      
    <xs:element name="castOnPartSeg">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:attribute name = "nextsnum"  type = "kpRefsList" use = "required"/>
        <xs:attribute name = "partNumber" type = "xs:nonNegativeInteger" use = "required"/>
        <xs:attribute name = "heightd" type = "decimal5digits" use = "required"/>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    
    <xs:element name="castOffPartPoint">
      <xs:complexType>
         <xs:attribute name ="previousnum" type = "kpRefsList" use = "required"/> 
        <xs:attribute name = "partNumber" type = "xs:nonNegativeInteger" use = "required"/>
        <xs:attribute name = "heightd" type = "decimal5digits" fixed = "0" use = "required"/>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    
    
    <xs:element name="castOffPartSeg">
     <xs:complexType>
        <xs:attribute name ="previousnum" type = "kpRefsList" use = "required"/> 
        <xs:attribute name = "partNumber" type = "xs:nonNegativeInteger" use = "required"/>
        <xs:attribute name = "heightd" type = "decimal5digits" fixed="0" use = "required"/>
      </xs:complexType> 
    </xs:element>

    
    <xs:element name="splitPart">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:attribute name ="previousnum" type = "kpRefsList" use = "required"/> 
        <xs:attribute name ="nextsnum" type = "kpRefsList" use = "required"/>
        <xs:attribute name = "partNumber" type = "xs:nonNegativeInteger" use = "required"/>
        <xs:attribute name = "heightd" type = "decimal5digits" use = "required"/>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    
    <xs:element name="segSplitPart">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:attribute name ="previousnum"  type = "kpRefsList" use = "required"/>        
        <xs:attribute name = "partNumber" type = "xs:nonNegativeInteger" use = "required"/>
        <xs:attribute name = "heightd" type = "decimal5digits" fixed= "0" use = "required"/>       
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    
    <xs:element name="joinPart">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:attribute name ="nextsnum"  type = "kpRefsList" use = "required"/>   
        <xs:attribute name ="previousnum" type = "kpRefsListmin2" use = "required"/>
         <xs:attribute name = "partNumber" type = "xs:nonNegativeInteger" use = "required"/>
         <xs:attribute name = "heightd" type = "decimal5digits" use = "required"/>      
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:simpleType name = "kpRefsList">
        <xs:list itemType= "xs:nonNegativeInteger"/>
    </xs:simpleType>
    
    <xs:simpleType name="kpRefsListmin2"> 
        <xs:restriction base = "kpRefsList"> 
        <xs:minLength value = "2"/>
      </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
  
   
    <xs:simpleType name ="decimal5digits">
        <xs:restriction base = "xs:decimal">
            <xs:fractionDigits value="5"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>    
</xs:schema>
```

It includes assertions in lines 28 and 29 which are incorrect . I have tried several solutions but being a complet newbie in XPath I did not make it. The goal is to test that every number in previousnum (same for nextsnum) is a valid partNumber for a part in the kPartsList of the kPartsPiece.

Below is an xml fragment which should be validated against the schema;

```
<ns0:kPartModel xmlns:ns0="http://www.ludd21.com/kPartModel" modelName="manysingulars">
<ns0:kPartsPiece pieceName="manysingulars">
    <ns0:kPartsList>
        <ns0:castOnPartSeg nextsnum="1" partNumber="0" heightd="11.82912" />
        <ns0:joinPart nextsnum="3" previousnum="0 2" partNumber="1" heightd="8.08932" />
        <ns0:castOnPartPoint nextsnum="1" partNumber="2" heightd="3.80881" />
        <ns0:joinPart nextsnum="6" previousnum="1 5 4" partNumber="3" heightd="8.65979" />
        <ns0:castOnPartSeg nextsnum="3" partNumber="4" heightd="16.36741" />
        <ns0:castOnPartSeg nextsnum="3" partNumber="5" heightd="6.48911" />
        <ns0:joinPart nextsnum="8 9 10" previousnum="3 7" partNumber="6" heightd="5.23755" />
        <ns0:castOnPartPoint nextsnum="6" partNumber="7" heightd="18.12524" />
        <ns0:splitPart previousnum="6" nextsnum="12" partNumber="8" heightd="8.63775" />
        <ns0:splitPart previousnum="6" nextsnum="11" partNumber="9" heightd="8.63775" />
        <ns0:segSplitPart previousnum="6" partNumber="10" heightd="0.00000" />
        <ns0:castOffPartSeg previousnum="9" partNumber="11" heightd="0.00000" />
        <ns0:castOffPartSeg previousnum="8" partNumber="12" heightd="0.00000" />
    </ns0:kPartsList>
</ns0:kPartsPiece>
```

</ns0:kPartModel>

Comment: It might be easier to make the `partNumber` an `xs:ID` and then the other two attributes `xs:IDREFS`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example a bit simplified but similar to your needs, with a list type and an assertion:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" vc:minVersion="1.1">
    <xs:element name="root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="parts"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="parts">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="part"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:assert id="test-reference-id" test="every $part in part satisfies every $id in $part/data(@next) satisfies some $part2 in part satisfies $id = $part2/@id"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="part">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="id" use="required" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:attribute name="next" type="id-list"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:simpleType name="id-list">
        <xs:list itemType="xs:string"></xs:list>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

The example

```
<root>
    <parts>
        <part id="p1" next="p2 p4"/>
        <part id="p2" next="p3 p4 p5"/>
        <part id="p3" next="p4"/>
        <part id="p4"/>
    </parts>
</root>
```

then fails the assertion while

```
<root>
    <parts>
        <part id="p1" next="p2 p4"/>
        <part id="p2" next="p3 p4"/>
        <part id="p3" next="p4"/>
        <part id="p4"/>
    </parts>
</root>
```

is valid.

My attempt to implement your assertions is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace = "http://www.ludd21.com/kPartModel"
    xmlns = "http://www.ludd21.com/kPartModel"
    elementFormDefault="qualified" 
    vc:minVersion = "1.1"
    xpathDefaultNamespace="##targetNamespace"
    xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning"
    >   
    <xs:element name="kPartModel">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="kPartsPiece"  minOccurs="1" maxOccurs = "unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="modelName" type="xs:NCName" use = "required"/>
        </xs:complexType>
        <!--piecename must be unique within kpModel-->
        <xs:unique name= "kPartModel">
            <xs:selector xpath="*"/>
            <xs:field xpath= "@pieceName"/>
        </xs:unique>
    </xs:element>
    
    <xs:element name="kPartsPiece">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref= "kPartsList"/>
            </xs:sequence>         
            <xs:attribute name="pieceName" type="xs:NCName"/>
            <!-- if they exist previousnum and nextsnum must contain valid partNumber that is referring to a part in kpartsList-->
            <xs:assert test = "every $x in data(kPartsList/*/@previousnum) satisfies some $part in kPartsList/* satisfies $part/@partNumber = $x"/>
            <xs:assert test = "every $x in data(kPartsList/*/@nextsnum) satisfies some $part in kPartsList/* satisfies $part/@partNumber = $x"/>
        </xs:complexType>
        <!-- @partNumber is unique across kPartsList -->
        <xs:unique name= "kPartsList">
            <xs:selector xpath="*/*"/>
            <xs:field xpath= "@partNumber"/>
        </xs:unique>
    </xs:element>
    
    <xs:element name = "kPartsList" >
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:choice >
                    <xs:element ref = "castOnPartSeg"/>
                    <xs:element ref = "castOnPartPoint"/>
                </xs:choice>
                <xs:choice  minOccurs= "0" maxOccurs = "unbounded">
                    <xs:element ref = "castOnPartSeg" />
                    <xs:element ref = "castOnPartPoint" />
                    <xs:element ref = "castOffPartSeg" />
                    <xs:element ref = "castOffPartPoint"/>
                    <xs:element ref = "joinPart"/>
                    <xs:element ref = "splitPart" />
                    <xs:element ref = "segSplitPart"/>  
                </xs:choice>
            </xs:sequence>        
        </xs:complexType>      
    </xs:element>
    
    
    <xs:element name="castOnPartPoint">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name ="nextsnum" type = "kpRefsList" use = "required"/>
            <xs:attribute name = "partNumber" type = "xs:nonNegativeInteger" use = "required"/>
            <xs:attribute name = "heightd" type = "decimal5digits" use = "required"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    
    <xs:element name="castOnPartSeg">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name = "nextsnum"  type = "kpRefsList" use = "required"/>
            <xs:attribute name = "partNumber" type = "xs:nonNegativeInteger" use = "required"/>
            <xs:attribute name = "heightd" type = "decimal5digits" use = "required"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    
    
    <xs:element name="castOffPartPoint">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name ="previousnum" type = "kpRefsList" use = "required"/> 
            <xs:attribute name = "partNumber" type = "xs:nonNegativeInteger" use = "required"/>
            <xs:attribute name = "heightd" type = "decimal5digits" fixed = "0" use = "required"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    
    
    <xs:element name="castOffPartSeg">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name ="previousnum" type = "kpRefsList" use = "required"/> 
            <xs:attribute name = "partNumber" type = "xs:nonNegativeInteger" use = "required"/>
            <xs:attribute name = "heightd" type = "decimal5digits" fixed="0" use = "required"/>
        </xs:complexType> 
    </xs:element>
    
    
    <xs:element name="splitPart">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name ="previousnum" type = "kpRefsList" use = "required"/> 
            <xs:attribute name ="nextsnum" type = "kpRefsList" use = "required"/>
            <xs:attribute name = "partNumber" type = "xs:nonNegativeInteger" use = "required"/>
            <xs:attribute name = "heightd" type = "decimal5digits" use = "required"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    
    <xs:element name="segSplitPart">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name ="previousnum"  type = "kpRefsList" use = "required"/>        
            <xs:attribute name = "partNumber" type = "xs:nonNegativeInteger" use = "required"/>
            <xs:attribute name = "heightd" type = "decimal5digits" fixed= "0" use = "required"/>       
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    
    <xs:element name="joinPart">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name ="nextsnum"  type = "kpRefsList" use = "required"/>   
            <xs:attribute name ="previousnum" type = "kpRefsListmin2" use = "required"/>
            <xs:attribute name = "partNumber" type = "xs:nonNegativeInteger" use = "required"/>
            <xs:attribute name = "heightd" type = "decimal5digits" use = "required"/>      
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    
    <xs:simpleType name = "kpRefsList">
        <xs:list itemType= "xs:nonNegativeInteger"/>
    </xs:simpleType>
    
    <xs:simpleType name="kpRefsListmin2"> 
        <xs:restriction base = "kpRefsList"> 
            <xs:minLength value = "2"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    
    
    <xs:simpleType name ="decimal5digits">
        <xs:restriction base = "xs:decimal">
            <xs:fractionDigits value="5"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>    
</xs:schema>
```

final model which passes in XMLSchema Python Package and validates correctly instances:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace = "http://www.ludd21.com/kPartModel"
    xmlns = "http://www.ludd21.com/kPartModel"
    elementFormDefault="qualified" 
    vc:minVersion = "1.1"
    xpathDefaultNamespace="##targetNamespace"
    xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning"
    >   
    <xs:element name="kPartModel">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="kPartsPiece"  minOccurs="1" maxOccurs = "unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="modelName" type="xs:NCName" use = "required"/>
        </xs:complexType>
        <!--piecename must be unique within kpModel-->
        <xs:unique name= "kPartModel">
            <xs:selector xpath="*"/>
            <xs:field xpath= "@pieceName"/>
        </xs:unique>
    </xs:element>
    
    <xs:element name="kPartsPiece">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref= "kPartsList"/>
            </xs:sequence>         
            <xs:attribute name="pieceName" type="xs:NCName"/>
            <!-- if they exist previousnum and nextsnum must contain valid partNumber that is referring to a part in kpartsList-->
            <xs:assert id = "test-nexts" test = "every $x in data(kPartsList/*/@nextsnum) satisfies some $part in kPartsList/* satisfies $part/@partNumber = $x"/>
        </xs:complexType>
        <!-- @partNumber is unique across kPartsList -->
        <xs:unique name= "kPartsList">
            <xs:selector xpath="*/*"/>
            <xs:field xpath= "@partNumber"/>
        </xs:unique>
    </xs:element>
    
    <xs:element name = "kPartsList" >
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:choice >
                    <xs:element ref = "castOnPartSeg"/>
                    <xs:element ref = "castOnPartPoint"/>
                </xs:choice>
                <xs:choice  minOccurs= "0" maxOccurs = "unbounded">
                    <xs:element ref = "castOnPartSeg" />
                    <xs:element ref = "castOnPartPoint" />
                    <xs:element ref = "castOffPartSeg" />
                    <xs:element ref = "castOffPartPoint"/>
                    <xs:element ref = "joinPart"/>
                    <xs:element ref = "splitPart" />
                    <xs:element ref = "segSplitPart"/>  
                </xs:choice>
            </xs:sequence>        
        </xs:complexType>      
    </xs:element>
    
    
    <xs:element name="castOnPartPoint">
        <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element ref ="basePoint"/>
        </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name ="nextsnum" type = "kpRefsList" use = "required"/>
            <xs:attribute name = "partNumber" type = "xs:nonNegativeInteger" use = "required"/>
            <xs:attribute name = "heightd" type = "decimal5digits" use = "required"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    
    <xs:element name="castOnPartSeg">
        <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element ref ="baseSeg"/>          
        </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name = "nextsnum"  type = "kpRefsList" use = "required"/>
            <xs:attribute name = "partNumber" type = "xs:nonNegativeInteger" use = "required"/>
            <xs:attribute name = "heightd" type = "decimal5digits" use = "required"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    
    
    <xs:element name="castOffPartPoint">
        <xs:complexType>
         <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element ref ="basePoint"/>
        </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name ="previousnum" type = "kpRefsList" use = "required"/> 
            <xs:attribute name = "partNumber" type = "xs:nonNegativeInteger" use = "required"/>
            <xs:attribute name = "heightd" type = "decimal5digits" fixed = "0" use = "required"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    
    
    <xs:element name="castOffPartSeg">
        <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element ref ="baseSeg"/>          
        </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name ="previousnum" type = "kpRefsList" use = "required"/> 
            <xs:attribute name = "partNumber" type = "xs:nonNegativeInteger" use = "required"/>
            <xs:attribute name = "heightd" type = "decimal5digits" fixed="0" use = "required"/>
        </xs:complexType> 
    </xs:element>
    
    
    <xs:element name="splitPart">
        <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element ref ="baseSeg"/>          
        </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name ="previousnum" type = "kpRefsList" use = "required"/> 
            <xs:attribute name ="nextsnum" type = "kpRefsList" use = "required"/>
            <xs:attribute name = "partNumber" type = "xs:nonNegativeInteger" use = "required"/>
            <xs:attribute name = "heightd" type = "decimal5digits" use = "required"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    
    <xs:element name="segSplitPart">
        <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element ref ="baseSeg"/>          
        </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name ="previousnum"  type = "kpRefsList" use = "required"/>        
            <xs:attribute name = "partNumber" type = "xs:nonNegativeInteger" use = "required"/>
            <xs:attribute name = "heightd" type = "decimal5digits" fixed= "0" use = "required"/>       
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    
    <xs:element name="joinPart">
        <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element ref ="baseSeg"/>          
        </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name ="nextsnum"  type = "kpRefsList" use = "required"/>   
            <xs:attribute name ="previousnum" type = "kpRefsListmin2" use = "required"/>
            <xs:attribute name = "partNumber" type = "xs:nonNegativeInteger" use = "required"/>
            <xs:attribute name = "heightd" type = "decimal5digits" use = "required"/>      
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    
     <xs:element name = "basePoint">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:attribute name= "start" type = "point" use = "required"/>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    
    
    <xs:element name = "baseSeg">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:attribute name= "start" type = "point" use = "required"/>
        <xs:attribute name= "end" type = "point" use = "required"/>
        <!--startY = endY!-->
        <!--<xs:assert test = "@start[1] = @end[1]"/> -->
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    
    <xs:simpleType name= "point">
        <xs:restriction>
          <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:list itemType = "decimal5digits"/>
          </xs:simpleType>
          <xs:length value = "2"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    
    <xs:simpleType name = "kpRefsList">
        <xs:list itemType= "xs:nonNegativeInteger"/>
    </xs:simpleType>
    
    <xs:simpleType name="kpRefsListmin2"> 
        <xs:restriction base = "kpRefsList"> 
            <xs:minLength value = "2"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    
    
    <xs:simpleType name ="decimal5digits">
        <xs:restriction base = "xs:decimal">
            <xs:fractionDigits value="5"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>    
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I understand from your suggestion that I need to define the element part. I need to rearrange the schema this way.

Comment: in modifying my xsd  I encounter 2 problems: 1  I input this into the online Liquid validator I get the following error :" cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'root'". . also should not it be for every $part in parts instead of in part

Comment: @piscvau, the sample in the answer was tested with Saxon EE and Apache Xerces in oXygen XML editor, I am afraid I am not familiar with the Liquid online validator, I guess it is https://www.liquid-technologies.com/online-xsd-validator and indeed when trying the samples from my answer it gives that error "cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'root'.". I don't know what that tool does under the hood, which parser it uses or how to set it up. The element is declared with e.g. `<xs:element name="root">`.

Comment: As for the XPath, no, in the context of the `parts` element we select downwards to the `part` child elements with e.g. `every $part in part`.

Comment: @piscvau, I have edited the answer to include an attempt to implement the assertions in your schema.

Comment: thank you for coping with my lack of knowledge about XPath and xml!...My xsd validator (that is Python XMLSchema package) validates wrong xml instances as well as good xml instances against your proposed assertion. It seems that it interprets incorrectly the data function but I am not sure.

Comment: @piscvau, I must admit that somehow, with the last schema using your original data and your original schema, I do not even seem to get conclusive validation of Xerces or Saxon, I haven't yet understand what fails and why. I am afraid I don't know the Python validation package, so someone else hopefully chimes in to tell us more.

Comment: the xsd I gave above is a simplified one and I just discovered that my python validator yells because I have complex type with no content. Below is a new xsd solving this problem

Comment: @piscvau, with some help on Slack I have managed to identify why the posted schema failed with Saxon and Xerces, it was just a typo in the XPath of one of the assertions. I have edited the sample in the answer and fixed the typo, now at least you should have an example schema that validates your input (with Saxonica Saxon and with Apache Xerces, as I said, don't know about that Python validator).

Comment: thanks a lot for your time. I cannot see the typo in the assertions!...

Comment: The reduced model as itself does not validate in my python package because the parts have no content:...However if I add a content it seems the assertion works OK , validating correct instances and not validating incorrect instances. So I am interested in the typo you corrected!....

Comment: Well, it is corrected, did that three hours ago, see above or if you need to see the change check https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72604282/revisions

Comment: Well thanks a lot. I did not know I could see the revisions. I will delete today my "false answer" and approve yours. And Thanks again.